Ubuntu Nginx Golang server returning 404
I have a Ubuntu server on which I installed PMPM and Golang 1.23.4.
When I go to my webaddress it only shows a gray page saying "404 page not found".
I build it on the server itself using the go build command. I then run it with PM2, but even when I run it manually with the command ./m, the pages will not be visible.
I do see my fmt.Prntln("") output that runs before the server starts, so I am sure the server starts correctly.
Also, when the server is not started, you will see a "502 Bad Gateway" page. When the server is active, you will see a "page not found" page.
My server block in NGINX:
server {

        root /var/www/website.com;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name website.com www.website.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8777;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }


    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

FYI my Nuxt website is working just fine, it is just the Golang server that ain't working properly.
When I do ps aux | grep 8777 it returns:
root      235889  0.0  0.0   7076  2176 pts/0    S+   10:43   0:00 grep --color=auto 8777

Does anyone have a clue what might be wrong.

No clue why, but on this server something is different. I had to prefix all my Go routes with /api/. So it is working now.
In previous projects I didn't need to add that prefix.

You don't need to use nginx to check if your golang application is listening. While you are at same host as your application - check it directly.
Attach logs from terminal where you start your golang application. It seems it's not runing at all. So - may be it was written with errors, may be require some args or envs and so on.
